# Rails 3. Not able to pass locals in a Partial js file with locals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, partial, locals

I have a lot of js files like new.js, index.js, create.js etc that handles my Ajax calls and other jquery code
As the have many common code snippets I have tried to use partial js files
For example I have a new.js file that calls a partial _new.js

new.js

```
    <%= render :partial=>'new',  :formats=>[:js],:handlers=>[:erb] %>
```

_new.js

```
    <% if params[:group_id]%>
      $("#group_participants_content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial=>'form'))%>");
      $(".remote_selected").removeClass("selected remote_selected simple-navigation-active-leaf");
      $("#group_mail").addClass(" remote_selected simple-navigation-active-leaf");
   <%else%>
     $("#users_content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial=>'form'))%>");
     $(".remote_selected").removeClass("selected remote_selected simple-navigation-active-leaf")
     $("#mail").addClass("remote_selected simple-navigation-active-leaf");
  <%end%>
  // Change our States
History.replaceState({action:'<%= "#{controller.action_name}/#{controller_name}" %>'}, '<%=       "#{controller.action_name.titleize} #{controller_name}" %>', '?action=<%=  "#{controller.action_name}/#{controller_name}" %>');
var url=History.getState().url;   
$("#help").attr('href',"/helps/0?url="+url)
```

That works but to be useful I would like to add locals as

```
    <%= render :partial=>'new',  :formats=>[:js],:handlers=>[:erb], :locals=>  {:id=>"#group_participants_content"}%>
```

and change _new.js to

```
  $('"'+id+'"').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial=>'form'))%>");
```

However that does not work- The js file seems then not to be loaded at all

Anyone that has any suggestion of what is wrong ?

Appreciate any help ?

Answer (score 1):

It's

```
$("<%=id%>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial=>'form'))%>");
```

Comment: No worries. Happy to be helpful. By the way, you may accept it as the answer if it's.

Answer (score 0):

The id coming is already in quotation, your code will wrap it again in quotation, pass it directly.Hope I should work:

```
$(id).html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial=>'form'))%>");
```